# use javascript to write a random <script>

Tags: javascript, random

How do I add a random 1 of 4 pre-defined `<script>`s to a webpage?

i.e. A 3rd party tool has 4 e-book download modal forms that are generated by a unique `<script>` (1 for each e-book).

I want to randomly add 1 of these `<script>`s to the page, so that on each page load, a different e-book download modal form is displayed.

How would I do this?

I've tried:

```
var min=1; 
var max=4;  
var random = Math.random() * (+max - +min) + +min; 

switch ($random) {
   case 1:
       document.write(<script src=""></script>)
   break;
```

but the `</script>` in the `document.write` closes the main `<script>`. Do I need to use HTML ascii code for the `<` & `>`?

Help appreciated.

**Update**:

The scripts I need added are in the format:

```
<script type='text/javascript' async='true' src='https://app.ontraport.com/js/ontraport/opt_assets/drivers/opf.js' data-opf-uid='p2c187780f17' data-opf-params='borderColor=#ec0c8d&borderSize=5px&formHeight=572&formWidth=60%&maxTriggers=2&onExitIntent=true&popPosition=mc&timeframe=1&instance=1067093054'></script>
```

Comment: Well, as a better and cleaner solution you can have one same script on each page with random links on Ebooks instead of 4 random scripts

Comment: You can just use `'<\/script>'` to avoid closing the script tag. But a better solution wouldn't use `document.write` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make a random selection of predefined script `src` URLs, and then dynamically add the `script` tag for it:

```
// List of possible attributes that script element could get
var scripts = [
    { src: "http://abc/scr1.js", "data-opf-uid": "23", "data-opf-params": "y='a'" },
    { src: "http://abs/scr2.js", "data-opf-uid": "81", "data-opf-params": "x=9" }
];
// Select a random entry from above list
var selected = scripts[Math.floor(Math.random()*scripts.length)];
selected.type='text/javascript';
// Create the script DOM element
var script = document.createElement('script');
// Assign the selected properties to the element as attributes
for (var prop in selected) {
    script.setAttribute(prop, selected[prop]);
}
// Add the element to the document
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Put this as a `script` in the `body` part of your document.

If the remote script is designed to be loaded in the `body` tag, then the last line should be changed to:

```
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

The properties you define in the above `scripts` object do not need any HTML escaping: that is taken care of when those properties are added to the generated `script` element using `setAttribute()`. You mention that your script needs the `async` attribute, but that is irrelevant for scripts that are added via code: they are anyway async. So no need (but also no harm) to add those.