# How to append <script> to current location in HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Previously, I used [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55215450/877797) to `document.head.appendChild(script);`.

This appended a `<script>` inside the `<head>`.

How do I append/insert the `<script>` at the current location / where the generating `<script>` is?

By generating script I mean the script I place somewhere in the body to generate 1 of 3 random `<script>`s at that location.

Help appreciated.

**Edit**, I've updated my original script to:

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var scripts = [
    { src: "https://app.ontraport.com/js/ontraport/opt_assets/drivers/opf.js", "data-opf-uid": "p2c187780f44", "data-opf-params": "borderColor=#22a8cc&borderSize=5px&embed=true&formHeight=633&formWidth=60%&popPosition=mc&instance=n768494876"},
    { src: "https://app.ontraport.com/js/ontraport/opt_assets/drivers/opf.js", "data-opf-uid": "p2c187780f45",  "data-opf-params": "borderColor=#22a8cc&borderSize=5px&embed=true&formHeight=633&formWidth=60%&popPosition=mc&instance=n1627526329" },
    { src: "https://app.ontraport.com/js/ontraport/opt_assets/drivers/opf.js", "data-opf-uid": "p2c187780f46", "data-opf-params": "borderColor=#22a8cc&borderSize=5px&embed=true&formHeight=633&formWidth=60%&popPosition=mc&instance=2011105601" },
];
// Add the element to the document
const currentScript = document.currentScript;
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const newScript = document.createElement('script');
  // Select a random entry from above list
  var selected = scripts[Math.floor(Math.random()*scripts.length)];
  selected.type='text/javascript';
  // Assign the selected properties to the element as attributes
  for (var prop in selected) {
    script.setAttribute(prop, selected[prop]);
  }
  newScript.textContent = 'console.log("new script"); console.log(document.body.innerHTML);';
  currentScript.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newScript);
 });
</script>
</div>
```

but this is not appending the script after the original script yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.currentScript` to refer to the current running script, and `insertAdjacentElement` to insert the new script after the running one:

```html
<div>
  <script>
    const newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.textContent = 'console.log("new script"); console.log(document.body.innerHTML);';
    document.currentScript.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newScript);
  </script>
</div>
```

If the first script inserts the other script asynchronously, you'll have to save a reference to the `currentScript` before the async callback runs:

```html
<div>
  <script>
    const currentScript = document.currentScript;
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const newScript = document.createElement('script');
      newScript.textContent = 'console.log("new script"); console.log(document.body.innerHTML);';
      currentScript.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newScript);
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks CP, I've adjusted my question to note the changes I've made to my script. Help appreciated.

Comment: A script can't have *both* a `src` and internal content. Remove the `textContent` part of your code, and it works for me

Comment: I'm not a JS developer, I've updated my question again to fix a syntax issue.

Comment: You need to use a consistent variable name, like in my answer: I'm using `newScript`. But you're using both `newScript` and `script`: `script.setAttribute(prop, selected[prop]);` Choose *one* name